# SQL Query Select all invoices and SUM values

Tags: sql

I have a db structure and am trying to select all the invoices with the respective employee and client, store etc.. also would like to sum the value of each invoice and present it as total

I made this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10
i.invoiceID, 
s.storeName, 
c.clientName,
sum(id.quantity * p.unitPrice) as total, 
(e.firstName + ' ' + e.lastName) as EmpName, 
i.invoiceDate

FROM
tbProduct p, 
tbInvoice i, 
tbInvoiceData id, 
tbEmployee e, 
tbStore s, 
tbClient c

WHERE
i.invoiceID = id.invoiceID
AND
e.employeeID = i.employeeID
AND
s.storeID = e.storeID
AND
c.clientID = i.clientID

GROUP BY
i.invoiceID,
s.storeName, 
c.clientName, 
e.firstName, 
e.lastName, 
i.invoiceDate

order by 
i.invoiceID
```

but the values in TOTAL don't seem correct (the sum part), what am I doing wrong... ?? because if I run this query:

```
select top 10
a.invoiceid, sum(a.quantity * b.unitprice) as total

from
tbInvoiceData a,
tbProduct b

where
a.productID = b.productID

group by
a.invoiceid
```

I get the correct values from the invoices.. :(

Comment: Take a look at the OVER clause: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-sever-2005-using-over-with-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY id.invoiceID

It seems that in the first query you are grouping from the table tbInvoice, but in the second you are grouping from tbInvoiceData. Don't know if that helps

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure if that would work or not. I do reckon it's something to do with your group by statement though

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got this... was forgeting this one...

> AND p.productID = id.productID

Thanks for the answer's